Six days before the Passover a weekly Sabbath?
John 12:1 states that Jesus arrived in Bethany six days before the Passsover. John places the Passover on Saturday, Nisan 15. This would mean Jesus arrived in Bethany on Nisan 9, a Sunday. But when on Nisan 9? At the beginning of Nisan 9 shortly after sunset as the day was beginning? Jesus and his disciples would have traveled the 18 miles from Jericho to Bethany (uphill). If they arrived just after sunset on Nisan 9 then Jesus was treated to a Supper and he was anointed. However, if Jesus entered Bethany during daytime Nisan 9 then the Supper would be either that afternoon or after sunset, hence, Nisan 10.
In John 12:12 says "the next day" Jesus went to Jerusalem. Does the "next day" mean the next daytime period or the next calendar day? The Greek words for "the next day" in John 12:12 is often translated as "on the morrow" in the KJV and I heard a sermon years ago this means the next daylight period, not the next calendar day. The word day here means the daylight portion of the day, or so say those that believe Nisan 9 was a Sabbath.
So, if Jesus entered Bethany just past sunset on Nisan 9, then the next day would be daytime but still on Nisan 9. Is this correct? If Jesus arrived in Bethany during the daytime Nisan 9 then the "next day" in John 12:12 would be Nisan 10, right? Most scholars claim the entry into Jerusalem was on Nisan 10, and they claim it was on a Sunday. But are they sure it was Sunday?
If John understood Passover to begin Nisan 14, a Friday, then six days before could be a Sabbath, Nisan 8. Since long distance travel was forbidden on the Sabbath, Jesus and his disciples could have made the 18 mile climb to Bethany on Friday Nisan 7 and arrived just past sunset on Nisan 8, the beginning of the Sabbath. But then in John 12:12 the "next day" would refer to the next calendar day, Sunday, Nisan 9. But this doesn't jive with tradition.

I think it'd be really helpful if you laid out the timeline that you're proposing and then where your question[s] are. Your title question is "is six days before Passover a weekly sabbath", and the answer is "it depends". Next year 15 Nisan 5785 is a shabbat, so 9 Nissan is the sunday

@AviAvraham Thanks for your answer. I modified my question a little. I have a problem with John placing the Passover meal on the evening following the crucifixion and the synoptics placing it on the beginning (after sunset, the beginning of our Thursday night) of the day Jesus died.

@SaberTruthTiger - ”John places the Passover on Saturday, Nisan 15.” How come? Scripture says Passover is on Nissan 14. ”If John understood Passover to begin Nisan 14, a Friday” How can we be sure that Nissan 14 was a Friday? Could you clarify on the basis of the Scripture and not “tradition”? I would like to test my conviction.

The synoptics gospels place the Passover on the same day Jesus and his disciples ate the Passover. The day began at sunset and they ate the dinner after sunset on the Passover meal. John, on the other hands, records Jesus and his disciples had a supper at the beginning of the day the Passover was sacrificed (the following afternoon). I don't have all the answers and I don't know how to balance these different descriptions of the Passover.

There are ten scripturally definable days. These days correlate to, or synchronize with, at least three definitive weekdays in the timeline. We know that he was crucified on the day of the preparation, which is Friday (Mk. 15:42; Lk. 23:54). The priests petitioned Pontius Pilate the day after the crucifixion, which Matthew calls, “the next day, that followed the day of the preparation,” which would be the Sabbath, or Saturday (Mat. 27:62). Christ then rose early on the first day of the week, which is Sunday (Mat. 28:1; Mk. 16:9; Lk. 24:1, 21; Jn. 20:1). The days of Passion week also correlate to, or synchronize with, at least one definitive Hebrew date we can identify, that being the first day of unleavened bread, when the passover is slain, which is the 14th day of Nisan (Mk. 14:12; Lk. 22:7; Mat. 26:17).
Projecting these pieces of definitive information forward and backward, we are able to assign both dates and days of the week for each of the scripturally defined days over the course of this ten-day period.
The First Definable Day — On the first definable day, Jesus passed through Jericho and abode at the home of Zaccheus, somewhere beyond Jericho, but between Jericho and Bethany (Lk. 19:1-10; Mat. 20:29-34; Mk. 10:46-52), no more than a Sabbath's day journey relative to ten definable days that terminate on the Sunday of the resurrection, showing that Jesus stayed with Zaccheus on Friday. He therefore had to be able to travel as far as Bethany on the Sabbath. Hints of him passing through Jericho on a Friday are even evident in that Jesus specifically says to Zaccheus, “Zaccheus, make haste, and come down; for today I must abide at thy house” (Lk. 19:5). Being a Friday, it would have been the day of preparation for the Sabbath, and it was obligatory under rabbinical law to establish a place of residence for the Sabbath, due to travel restrictions, as mentioned. This was done every week on the day of preparation, even if the person in question had to declare a random plot of ground in the wilderness his residence (Read the Talmud, Erubin, for more information). Jesus basically told Zaccheus that he needed to “dwell” at his home so he would have a place to call his residence for the Sabbath. Additionally, Jesus told him to make haste, which further implies that time was of the essence. This had to be done before sunset when the Sabbath began.
The Second Definable Day — From this legal place of residence, depending on the actual location of Zaccheus’ house, when Jesus departed on the second of our ten days, Saturday, he would have been able to travel a certain distance on the Sabbath, allowing him to make it to Bethany, six days before the Passover, where he resided until the next day (Mat. 21:1; Mk. 11:1; Lk. 19:29; Acts 1:12; Jn. 11:18, 12:1). Although Matthew, Mark, and Luke all give the impression that he proceeded directly to Jerusalem when he reached the area of Bethphage and Bethany, John is clear that it was the following day that he sent two disciples to acquire the ass that he rode into the city (Mat. 21:1-17; Mk. 11:1-11; Lk. 19:28-46; Jn. 12:1, 12-16). This was six days before the passover (Jn. 12:1), which, according to the counting methods of the time period, should be inclusive, where the six days includes the day of the Passover itself, consistent with the mathematical culture of the era. Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday are six days. Ergo, six days before the Passover, by this example, is Saturday, making one day before the Passover, which enumeration would be inclusive of the Passover itself, Thursday.
The Third Definable Day — As already stated, Matthew, Mark, and Luke all give the impression that Jesus rode directly into Jerusalem once he reached Bethphage and Bethany. However, John clearly tells us that it was “the next day” that this happened, defining the third day in the Passion week as being the day following his arrival in Bethany, when Jesus sent two of his disciples to acquire the ass and colt so he could ride into Jerusalem in fulfillment of prophecy (Jn. 12:12-16; Mat. 21:1-17; Mk. 11:1-11; Lk. 19:28-46). This would have been five days before the Passover. After arriving at the temple on the day of his triumphal entry into Jerusalem, Jesus looked around and departed at eventide to return to Bethany (Mk. 11:11. The separation of days shown in Mark occurs between Mat. 21:11 and 21:12).
The Fourth Definable Day — Jesus came back to Jerusalem the next morning, Monday, which was four days before the Passover (Mk. 11:12). This is the fourth definable day in the chronology. He went into the temple and drove out the moneychangers, and those who were buying and selling. While the accounts in Matthew and Luke suggest that this event is part of the previous day, that he rode into Jerusalem and immediately drove out the merchants and money-changers, Mark clarifies for us, as previously noted, that the day Jesus rode into Jerusalem, he merely went into the temple and looked round about, and then departed back to Bethany at eventide (Mat. 21:2-12; Lk. 19:28-45; Mk. 11:11). It wasn’t until the next morning that he returned to the temple and drove these people out. Once that was done, he then left at “eventide” and returned to Bethany where he stayed the night (Mat. 21:12-17; Mk. 11:12-19; Lk. 19:45-46).
The Fifth Definable Day — On the following morning, the fifth definable day, which was Tuesday, and three days before the Passover according to John’s reckoning, Jesus returned to Jerusalem and taught in the temple. The chief priests and elders challenged his authority, and several groups, including the Herodians, Sadducees, lawyers, and Pharisees, took turns throughout the day tempting him with challenging questions and scenarios designed to undermine his particular theosophy. Perhaps in response to their deliberate attempts to tempt him, or perhaps because he was just fed up with their hypocrisy at that specific moment in time, Jesus delivers the infamous woes to the scribes, the lawyers, and the Pharisees. After which, he departed the temple and went to the Mount of Olives, where he revealed in his Olivet Discourse the things that were soon to come (Mat. 21:18-25:46; Mk. 11:20-13:37; Lk. 19:45-21:37).
The Sixth Definable Day — The next morning, Wednesday, the sixth definable day and two days before the Passover, people came to hear him in the temple (Lk. 21:37-38). Jesus was later invited to supper in Bethany at the house of Simon the Pharisee, who tended to the lepers (Mat. 26:6; Mk. 14:3). Lazarus, the brother of Martha and Mary, whom Jesus raised from the dead, was present (Jn. 12:2). During the meal, Mary came in with an alabaster box filled with a very costly ointment of spikenard. She washed Jesus’ feet and anointed them with the ointment. She then sat at his feet to hear his words while her sister Martha served the meal (Mat. 26:7; Mk. 14:3; Jn. 12:2).
This supper, again, was two days before the Passover by John’s reckoning, consistent with the statements of Matthew and Mark, who both tell us that “after two days was the Passover” (Mat. 26:1-2; Mk. 14:1). Chronologically speaking, this demonstrates a competent timeline up to this point. Further, recalling to mind the story of Peter and Cornelius, we’re dealing with inclusive counting. Even more particularly, knowing that the three days from Christ’s crucifixion to his resurrection includes Friday in the count, both the phraseology and methodology here is the same. It is mentioned twice that he would rise “after three days,” which meant three days in cardinal numbers, the third day in ordinal numbers, and was, in both instances, inclusive of the day of the event (Mat. 27:63-64; Mk. 8:31). I can’t stress enough that while I know that this type of counting sounds strange to our modern minds, having been brought up taking the number zero for granted, this is how they counted. Thus, the day of the supper at Simon’s house was one day, and the day of the Passover was two days, meaning that the Passover was the next day. The gospels confirm this in the immediate continuation of the narrative, which is the first day of unleavened bread, when they killed the Passover (Mat. 26:17; Mk. 14:12; Lk. 22:7).
The Seventh Definable Day — The next day, the seventh definable day of Passion week, was the 14th day of Nisan, and oddly counted as one day before the Passover, though it was the day of the Passover itself. However, compare this to the day of the kalends in the Roman calendar, which is the day of, but deduces to “one day before the kalends” if you consider it. Also, Cornelius, whose present day would have deduced to “one day ago” in Acts 10:1-30. So, too, do John's "six days before the Passover" and Matthew's and Mark's "after two days" apply here in the same fashion. The day of the Passover deduces to “one day before the Passover,” just as the next day, counted inclusively, is "after two days," however strange this may seem to us.
On this seventh day of Passion week, Mark and Luke are both explicit in stating that it was the first day of unleavened bread, when the Passover lamb had to be slain. Matthew also states that it was the first-most day of unleavened bread, which is the 14th, when all leaven had to be burned (Mk. 14:12; Lk. 22:7; cf. Mat. 26:17). Jesus sent two disciples that afternoon to prepare the Passover, and they did as they were instructed. Jesus was arrested later that night and put on trial (Mat. 26:17; Mk. 14:12; Lk. 22:7).
The Eighth Definable Day — On the eighth definable day, Jesus was brought before Pontius Pilate, condemned, and crucified (Mk. 15:1; Mat. 27:1; Lk. 22:66; Jn. 18:28). The priests refused to enter Pilate’s palace because they didn’t want to be defiled. They wanted to eat the Passover. The previous day, according to three other gospels, was the first day of unleavened bread, which is the 14th. The previous day, according to two of those three gospels, was also the day when the Passover was sacrificed, which is the 14th. Therefore, this Passover meal, we know by context, was Hagigah, or the Passover of the 15th, also known as the festive offering (bPesah 69a-70b). It was equally obligatory in Jewish law, and while there can only be one day that can be considered the “first” day of unleavened bread, there were two feasts referred to as the Passover. Compare this to Deut. 16:1-2, which includes Passover sacrifices from the herd, which is cattle, whereas the Passover of the 14th has to come from the flock, meaning the sheep or goats. The Talmud makes the same argument.
The Ninth Definable Day — The ninth definable day was the Sabbath. The disciples, men and women, rested according to the commandment. Matthew refers to this day as the day following the preparation, which is the Sabbath. Given the confusion that can come from simply using the word “Sabbath” to describe that specific day during Passover week, Matthew called it the Sabbath circumlocutively to avoid that confusion. The 15th of Nisan was considered a Sabbath relative to the holiday and the count to Pentecost. According to the scholiast to the Megillat Ta’anit, the Pharisees triumphed over the Sadducees concerning the interpretation of מִֽמָּחֳרַת֙ הַשַּׁבָּ֔ת, or the “morrow after the Sabbath,” the Sadducees advocating for the count to begin on the Sunday following the first weekly Sabbath, and the Pharisees arguing for the day following the holy convocation of the 15th (Zeitlin, MegTaan, 75; bMenah. 65a-66a). Despite any current theological positions on the subject, the convocation of the 15th, as a matter of historical fact, was determined in practice to be a Sabbath, since the 16th of the first month became the official starting point for the count to Pentecost. Relative to the confusion that could result from the careless use of the word "Sabbath" during Passover week, it is my opinion that Matthew is being deliberate in this instance. Only the Saturday Sabbath was the day following the day of the preparation, which itself specifically denoted the sixth day of the week. The 15th could only be considered the day following the preparation if it happened to coincide with the weekly Sabbath.
The Tenth Definable Day — On the first day of the week, Christ was risen. It was the third day since he was condemned and crucified. It was the tenth definable day.
This is the documented chronology of Passion week according to the particular details afforded to us by the gospels as a whole. The Synoptics and John line up dead on the money, from six days before the Passover to the third day falling on the first day of the week. Ten discernable days can be accounted for, paralleled, and corroborated from gospel to gospel. So the timeline is as follows:
Day 01: Friday, Nisan 8, Jesus passes through Jericho and stays with Zaccheus.
Day 02: Saturday, Nisan 9, Jesus travels a Sabbath's distance to Bethany.
Day 03: Sunday, Nisan 10, Jesus rides into Jerusalem on lamb selection day.
Day 04: Monday, Nisan 11, Jesus drives out the merchants and money-changers.
Day 05: Tuesday, Nisan 12, Jesus delivers the infamous woes.
Day 06: Wednesday, Nisan 13, Jesus has dinner at the house of Simon.
Day 07: Thursday, Nisan 14, day the lambs were sacrificed, the last supper, and Jesus arrested.
Day 08: Friday, Nisan 15, Jesus is crucified. The Jews use a gentile to carry out an execution they can't do themselves because of the holiday Sabbath.
Day 09: Saturday, Nisan 16, the Sabbath. The tomb is sealed and guarded.
Day 10: Sunday, Nisan 17, Jesus is resurrected in the early morning hours.

In this answer:

Jewish calendar dates and Sabbath refer to days delimited according to Jewish day reckoning, from sunset to sunset;

Pagan names of days of the week refer to days delimited according to Roman day reckoning, from midnight to midnight.


Thus Sabbath is NOT the same as Saturday, but spans from Friday sunset to Saturday sunset.
Timeline
Nisan 8, 7 days before Passover: from Friday sunset to Saturday sunset. It is a Sabbath so no physical work is performed, such as walking or cooking.
Nisan 9, 6 days before Passover: from Saturday sunset to Sunday sunset.

Sunday morning: Jesus and his disciples walk from wherever they were to Bethany. This is more plausible than a night walk.
Sunday around noon: Jesus and his disciples arrive at Lazarus' home, refresh themselves after the walk, and take some rest.
Meanwhile, during Sunday daytime, Lazarus' sisters buy and cook the food and prepare the room for the dinner.

Nisan 10, 5 days before Passover: from Sunday sunset to Monday sunset.

Sunday evening: the dinner for Jesus is held at Lazarus' home.
Monday around noon: Jesus enters Jerusalem, just when the Paschal lambs are being taken into Jerusalem to be bought by the Jewish households for the oncoming Passover.

Nisan 11, 4 days before Passover: from Monday sunset to Tuesday sunset.
Nisan 12, 3 days before Passover: from Tuesday sunset to Wednesday sunset.
Nisan 13, 2 days before Passover: from Wednesday sunset to Thursday sunset.
Nisan 14, 1 day before Passover: from Thursday sunset to Friday sunset.

Thursday evening: Jesus eats the Last Supper with his disciples.
Thursday night: Jesus is taken prisoner and taken to Annas' and then to Caiaphas' and questioned by the Sanhedrin.
Friday morning: Jesus is taken to the Praetorium, questioned by Pilate, flogged and crucified.
Friday afternoon: Jesus dies between 15:00 and 16:00, just when the Paschal lambs are being slaughtered in the Temple.
Friday just before sunset: Jesus is buried.

Nisan 15, the day of Passover: from Friday sunset to Saturday sunset.

Friday evening: Jews eat the Passover meal.

